# Pass parameters in unit event testing karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, watch

Testing an function like this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $injector){
    service = $injector.get('service');
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    createController = function() {
        return $controller('mainCtrl', {
            '$scope': scope
        });
    };
}));

$scope.$watch('value', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if(newVal != oldVal)
      service.setValue(newVal);  
});
```

With a test like this:

```
it("$watch value",function(){
        spyOn(service,'setValue').andCallThrough();
        var controller=createController();
        scope.value = true;
        expect(service.setValue).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

And the spy is never triggered because of the condition.
How can I trigger this watch event with the parameters in order to test if the service is called?

Comment: Please share controller with watch call

Comment: I am sorry I am not getting which code do you mean. The controller part is on the top of the post.

Comment: Ys,I want tha part with controller

Comment: Please share beforeEach script with service

Comment: I have added answer.Please let me know if you have any problem

Answer (score 0):

Please do following changes :

You need to use `scope.$apply();` to update the binding and `contoller as` syntax to get the `controller.value`;

While defining controller use **this** instead of **scope** so,variable get easily available in Jasmine.

**Jasmine script** :

```
describe("test", function() {

    var Service, scope, controller;

    beforeEach(module('inspinia'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $injector, serviceData) {
        Service = serviceData;

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('mainCtrl as ctrl', {
            $scope: scope
        });;

    }));

    it("$watch value", function() {

          spyOn(Service,'setValue').and.callThrough();
          controller.value = 1120;
          scope.$apply();
          controller.value = 1121;
          scope.$apply();         
         expect(Service.setValue).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
})
```

**Angular script** :

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('inspinia', [])
        .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, serviceData) {

            var ctrl = this;
            ctrl.value = 1230;
            $scope.$watch('ctrl.value', function(newVal, oldVal) {


                if (newVal != oldVal) {
                    console.log(newVal, oldVal, newVal !== oldVal);
                    serviceData.setValue(newVal);
                }
            });

        })
        .factory('serviceData', function() {

            var obj = {};

            obj.setValue = function() {

                console.log(1010)

            }
            return obj;
        });
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But there is no way of passing the newVal and OldVal through the test, right? Since we cannot do that the condition  if (newVal != oldVal)  will never be satisfied and serviceData.setValue(newVal); will never get called. That's the issue I am facing

Comment: Please run my code snippet. It is getting called.checj console